# Unable to create posts in rails forum on the topics page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, forum, posts

I am new to rails and am trying create a forum. The forum has many topics, topics belong to a forum and have many microposts, and microposts belong to both topics and users. However, no matter what I try, the posts will not be created. Currently when I try to post, I get the routing error "No route matches [GET] "/topics""

My routes.rb file:

```
resources :users 
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :forums, only: [:index, :show]
resources :topics, only: [:show]
```

_micropost_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, value: @topic.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.text_field :summary, placeholder: "One-line summary..." %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose a new post..." %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

def create
    #@topic = Topic.find_by_id(params[:topic_id])
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Your solution has been posted!"
        redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
    else
        redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
    end
end

def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
end

private

    def micropost_params
        params.require(:micropost).permit(:summary, :content, :user_id)
    end

    def correct_user
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

As you can see, I commented out the first line in my create function because I've tried posting based on the the micropost's relationship to the topic to no avail. Thanks in advance and let me know if it would help if I posted more code!

Answer (score 0):

In your `:topics` resource, you didn't defined the index method, that's why you won't be able to get to topic's list or index page. Try to change your route like this:

```
resources :topics, only: [:index, :show]
```

or remove only attribute from resources, it will automatically include all your methods by default.

```
resources :topics
```

Also if you have relationship between models, you should define nested routes in your routes
file, For example, you can define them like this, you can change them accordingly:

try to change your route file like this:

```
resources :users 
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

resources :forums do
  resources :topics do
    resources :microposts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  
  end
end
```

In above case, you can access your forums like this:

```
 http://localhost:3000/forums
```

you can access your topics like this:

```
 http://localhost:3000/forums/id/topics
```

you can access your microposts like this:

```
 http://localhost:3000/forums/id/topics/id/microposts
```

If you want to access `/microposts` directly you have to put it outside any resource.

```
resources :microposts, only: [:index]
```

now you will be able to access it:

```
 http://localhost:3000/microposts
```

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it still isn't working for me :( First I added an index to the route and topics controller, but it ended up just directing me to the /topics page and didn't save the micropost. Seems like since it didn't save, it was just redirected, and to the wrong page... Additionally, after I changed my route file and hit submit, I got the routing error "No route matches [POST] "/microposts""- do I need to do more than just change the route file?

Comment: remove :only options from microposts as well. that it will redirects to all routes.